# Using R to Download and extract zip file that contains a folder

Tags: r

In Rstudio I wrote:

```
urlcoP <- "http://www.cophieu68.vn/datax123456/metastock_all_data.zip"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(urlcoP,temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "metastock_all_data.txt"))
```

But it's get the error:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot locate file 'metastock_all_data.txt' in zip file 'C:\TEMP\RtmpaaH3PW\file135c1e97348'
```

The reason is that the `metastock_all_data.txt` is in a folder called `datax123456` in the zip.

Answer (score 3):

try this?

```
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "datax123456/metastock_all_data.txt"))
```

metastock_all_data.txt is in a folder called datax123456 in the zip, hence add the folder before metastock_all_data.txt

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: I guess @chinsoon12 has defined the zip file location first, that was missing and creating error previously.

Comment: Your code is not fire in Rstudio, and i find a solution of it by run the code: data <- read.csv(unzip(temp),header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)