# Errors when trying to download ZIP file from URL

Tags: r, download, zip

I am trying to download a ZIP file in R and to extract a CSV.
I've found a couple of solutions on StackOverFlow, e.g.
[Using R to Download and extract zip file that contains a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385170/using-r-to-download-and-extract-zip-file-that-contains-a-folder),

but I am getting errors messages.
My code:

```
url <- 'https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilit%C3%A4ts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip'

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url,temp)
```

Error output (translated from German):

Error in download.file(url, temp) :
could not open URL 'https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilit%C3%A4ts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip'
Additional Warning:
In download.file(url, temp) :
URL 'https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilit%C3%A4ts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an SSL problem which is usually a `curl` isse - [Get site content over SSL with httr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913916/get-site-content-over-ssl-with-httr-in-r): Might try to follow those suggested solutions as the following code worked for me:

```
Modalsplit <- read.csv(unz(temp, "Modalsplit_pro_Tag.csv"))
Mittelwerte <- read.csv(unz(temp, "Mittelwerte_und_Median_pro_Tag.csv"))
Distanz <-read.csv(unz(temp, "Mittelwerte_und_Median_pro_Tag.csv"))
```